# DB2 Varchar field length

Tags: performance, db2

I am confused whether to choose varchar length of 255 or 256 for a varchar field in DB2.

What will be a good size for performance? From my search on google it looks like 255 is best because it's equal to 1 byte.  Which is right?  Does varchar(255) require 1 byte or does varchar(256) require 1 byte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I think that reading one byte or two bytes for a variable length column will not create a lot of impact. The fact that this length will be used to analyze how many characters to read in a row is more penalizing (two operations, one for quantity and one for data).

You could think that one extra byte in for example a table with one million records is a lot of unnecessary disk space, but with the compression feature activated this is not really a concern related to Storage (IO) nor with processing (CPU).

By the way:
255 = 11111111 (one byte)
256 = 100000000 (two bytes)

The only recommendation is to use a varchar for columns with more that 30 characters, otherwise the best is to use a fix length column CHAR, because the overhead of reading the length plus the data is a lot comparing the quantity of data to read when few characters. ( http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0404mcarthur/ )

Comment: Another interesting reason to use CHAR if it's a small field: when doing a sort, the DBB engine will pad spaces to the full length of the varchar.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.perf%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_improvesortprocessing.htm